# Is it possible to export all my iPhone contacts to my iPad 2?

Tags: iphone, ipad, data-synchronization, icloud, contacts

Does anyone know of a way to export all my contacts from my iPhone straight into my iPad 2 without having to re-type all of them in?

Answer (score 7):

- register for iCloud on source device (iPhone)
- enable iCloud syncing for Contacts
- wait about 10 minutes
- login to iCloud on target device (iPad)
- enable Contacts syncing
- wait a few minutes

[Info about iCloud](http://www.apple.com/icloud/features/contacts-calendar-mail.html)

Comment: hmmm... aren't developers under the NDA which forbids them from releasing _this_ sort of information?

Comment: Screenshot removed, but similar info is on the iCloud page on apple.com.

Comment: This answer should come with an actual time machine.

Answer (score 3):

Sync from iPhone to your computer, then from the computer to the iPad.

---

When I got my iPhone I was also able to transfer all data and apps from an iPod touch backup to it. Maybe you can do something similar with the iPad and an iPhone backup.

Answer (score 3):

I would advise to directly [transfer iPhone contacts](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/3308-how-to-transfer-iphone-contacts-to-ipad-without-itunes-or-the-icloud/) to your iPad without the using the iCloud or iTunes.

The last time I tried to transfer my old iPhone contacts to my new iPhone via iTunes sync, it wiped clean my old iPhone - not a pleasant experience.

Answer (score 2):

In iTunes, click your phone's name > Information tab > tick the box to sync contacts and choose Windows Contacts, then do the same process for your iPad and sync.

Answer (score 0):

You can always sync your contacts with iTunes to your computer and then to your iPad.

---

If you're looking for a PC/Mac-less experience of transferring your contacts over, try [iDrive Lite](http://www.idrive.com/idrive-lite/index.html) (App Store link [here](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/idrive-lite/id295113646?mt=8%27)). It can backup and restore your contacts between devices using a free account.

Answer (score 0):

Download an app called [Bump](http://bu.mp/) to both devices. It uses Bluetooth to transfer stuff, you can tell it to transfer all contacts.

Answer (score 0):

**Copy Trans Contacts** is software that will give u full control over your iPhone contacts.

It will allow u to back up all your iPhone contacts to a PC & then transfer those contacts to your iPad.

http://www.copytrans.net/copytranscontacts.php

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple.

1. Download any iPhone **Contact** App from the AppStore on your iPad with same apple ID , (I downloaded the App **Groups** on my Ipad)
2. import all your iPad contacts to that app
3. Download the same app on your iPhone (depending on your settings, this might happen automatically)
4. On your iPad contact app, there is an option to email your contacts. Send them via email from the iPad and open that mail on your iPhone.
5. The e-mail will have an attachment; open that attachment on iPhone and add it to the contact app on your iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Export all your contacts of the old Phone in iCloud as one vCard, including all Contacts and send it as an email to your new Device.

see: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/101656/31470